# Add on to SP in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

Was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to add on to a stored procedure using SSRS?  I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that is manipulating data to create a great base. I then want to use that stored procedure and transform it some more inside SSRS depending on the reports I am doing.

Is this even possible?

Thanks,

Comment: SSRS just uses SQL Server for its data - SSRS isn't a database system of its own, you cannot write proper T-SQL stored procedures *in SSRS*. If you need an extra stored procedure for your report, write it in SQL Server and just use it from SSRS

Comment: Inside of SSRS you can write Visual Basic code (including functions) to further process data

Comment: That's what I thought but was hoping there was an obscure way I did not know about.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do? At the moment the question is very vague

Comment: I will rephrase in a new question.  Thanks.